# JLayeredPane repaint removes some images

Tags: java, image, swing, jlayeredpane

I need a UI where i want to depict a network device's graphical representation in swing. For this, i am just loading multiple images and overlap them one by one to show the current state of the device. I have to support zooming for this view. The zoom code looks like this.

```
public void zoom(double factor){
    if (factor < MIN_ZOOM_VALUE)
        factor = MIN_ZOOM_VALUE;
    else if (factor > MAX_ZOOM_VALUE)
        factor = MAX_ZOOM_VALUE;

    scaleFactor = factor;

    layeredPane.revalidate();
    layeredPane.repaint();
}
```

The images are added as labels.

```
private class ImageLabel extends JLabel{

    private ImageIcon image;
    private Position position;

    public ImageLabel(ImageIcon image, Position position){
        super(image);
        this.image = image;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        int newX = (int)(position.getLeft() * scaleFactor);
        int newY = (int)(position.getTop() * scaleFactor);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        int newW = (int)(position.getWidth() * scaleFactor);
        int newH = (int)(position.getHeight() * scaleFactor);

        setBounds(newX, newY, newW, newH);

        g2.setRenderingHint(
                     //RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                    //RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.drawImage(image.getImage(), 0, 0, newW, newH, null);

    }
}
```

But the problem here is, when i zoom in once and zoom out, some of the images disappear. Any idea why it behaves like this?

Comment: try to use
`AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x,y);   
        at.scale(scale, scale);   
        g2.drawRenderedImage(image, at)`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) `g2.drawImage(image.getImage(), 0, 0, newW, newH, null);`  A `JLabel` *is* an `ImageObserver`so that should best be `g2.drawImage(image.getImage(), 0, 0, newW, newH, this);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 to @AndrewThompsons comment.

The only other problem I can see is you dont honor the *paint chain*.

Also always remember to honor the *paint chain* by calling `super.XXX` implementation of overriden paint methods (and for that matter any overriden method), unless you know what you are doing and are purposely not calling their `super`s implementation, or else visual artifacts like the ones you describe could/will happen.

To do this you would call `super.paintComponent(Graphics g)` as the first method in overridden `paintComponent` like so:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);

     //do other drawings here
}
```

Also note how I use `@Override` annotation so that I am sure I am overriding the correct method.

Comment: Thnx. But it still not working ... when we zoom out from the view port images disappear.